# Where's the header files information in the compiled file (assemble file)?

Tags: c

I used the `GCC -E` command, and I can see the #include files are pasted in after preprocessing. But when I use the `GCC -S` command, in the generated assemble file(**.s**), I can't find information about my header files.(More specifically, whether I comment the #include  instruction, I get the same .s file).
Next step I can use `gcc -o *.s` to assemble and link my **.s** file. But where did **GCC** get the header file information?

Comment: What information is there in the header file that you think is important for the final compiled executable?

Comment: preprocessed source files are not compiled yet. Once compiled, headers disappear.

Comment: @StoryTeller In my underderstanding, if the executable uses a dynamic lib(.dll), it also needs a .h file to get information, e.g. the declarations of the functions. So, the exe doesn't need to contain the .h, but is needs to specify which .h it uses. That's what I think the #include *.h instruction is for. So I'm wondering where's the #include *.h information in the assemble file. Anyway, if the header file information is lost, why do we need to write #include instruction in the source file？

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Why...  so where has the missing information gone？  pls see my comments above also

Comment: @nebulaf91 Normally header files only contains declarations e.g. declarations that a certain function exists, its return type and its arguments. Or the declaration of a struct, so your code can that struct. If your code then uses/calls a function declared in that header file, the compiler can check that the syntax is correct. There normally nothing in that header file to be placed in the exe file. If you call a function, the compiler/linker just translates that to a memory address which it writes to the exe file.

Comment: @nebulaf91: I'm sorry to tell you, but your "understanding" on how libraries/DLLs work is wrong. Any kind of linkable binary exposes what's known as "symbols". The symbols exported by linkable binaries can be listed with e.g. `nm`, `objdump -t` and similar tools. However these symbols by themself do not carry any information what exactly they refer to, they're just a table of contents, what exactly lies behind a symbol however is not important at link time anyway. *It is important at the code generation stage, though!* that's why a header file or other information is required for compilation.

Answer (score 1):

The `#include` statements in the preprocessed outputs are there to link to the header file in case the compiler finds an error and wants to notify the user about the specific location of the error ("included in xxx.h")

But all code/declarations contained in the `#include` (provided they match the proper `#ifdef/#if` conditions) are expanded in the preprocessed output. Only this code/declaration stuff is used by the compiler to produce the assembly / binary object file, no more need for the headers at that point.

So your assembly code has already integrated the information of the header files (structure offsets, constants, type sizes...) and it's no longer C anymore, it's assembly.